# Using Select in an Edit Form Laravel

Tags: laravel

Im trying to implement a Edit function to update permissions from an Laravel User, (I already installed Spatie), it parcially works, it save the changes but I cant see the permissions of the role on the Select Form. Any help please

```
<--CONTROLLER-->
    public function edit($id)
        {
            $role = Role::findById($id);
            $permissions = Permission::all();
            return view('admin_roles_edit', compact('role','permissions', 'permissions1'));
        }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $request->validate([
                'name'=>'required|max:30',
            ]);
            $role = Role::findById($id);
            $role->update($request->all());
            $role->permissions()->sync($request->permissions);
            return redirect()->route('admin.roles.index')->with('message', 'El rol se ha actualizado correctamente');
        }
<--HTML-->
    <form action="{{route('admin.roles.update', $role->id)}}" method="post"
                                  class="form">
                                @csrf

                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Nombre<span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
                                           value="{{$role->name}}" required="required">
                                    @error('name')
                                    <label class="validation-error-label" for="basic">{{$message}}</label>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Permisos<span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="multi-select-full">
                                        <select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="roles">
                                        @foreach($permissions as $permission)
                                            <option value="{{$permission->id}} @if($permission->id == $role->permission) selected @endif">{{$permission->name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group pull-right">
                                    <a href="{{route('admin.roles.index')}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i
                                                class="icon-cross2 position-left"></i>Cancelar
                                    </a>
                                    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn btn btn-success"><i
                                                class="icon-add position-left"></i>Editar
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
<--RESULT-->
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your controller add this line:

```
 public function edit($id)
        {
            $role = Role::findById($id);
            $permissions = Permission::all();
            $rolePermissions = $role->permissions()->pluck('name','id')->toArray();
            return view('admin_roles_edit', compact('role','permissions', 'rolePermissions'));
        }
```

update your blade:

```
 <option value="{{$permission->id}}" {{in_array($permission->id, array_keys($rolePermissions)) ? 'selected' : '')}}>{{$permission->name}}</option>
```

Comment: Already try your solution and I got this error: ParseError
Unmatched ')' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ember\resources\views\admin_roles_edit.blade.php)
http://localhost/ember/public/roles/1/edit

Comment: are you sure this error related to my solution?

Comment: Well I never seen that error before until I try your solution

Answer (score 0):

Fixed finally
RoleController.php

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $role = Role::findById($id);
        $permissions = Permission::all();
        return view('admin_roles_edit', compact('role','permissions'));
    }
```

RoleView.blade.php

```
<select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="roles">
                                            @foreach($permissions as $permission)
                                                <option value="{{$permission->id}}"
                                                @if($role->hasPermissionTo($permission->id))
                                                selected="selected"
                                                @endif/>{{$permission->name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
```

[Fixed Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NF7Nj.png)